# Как используют библиотеки с разными версиями языка в одном проекте?

Tags: c++

Собственно, вопрос в заголовке. На сколько я понял, разные версии языка вводят разные ограничения и предоставляют разные возможности. Я не программирую на c++ и мне интересно, возможно ли использовать например библиотеки написанные на c++98 в проекте c++17? И если да, то с какими ограничениями? Как это работает? Не могу найти информацию об этом в гугле

Comment: большинство возможностей языка применяются при компиляции, уже скомпилированный двоичный код, коим и являются библиотеки от языка слабо зависят. по хорошему они могут быть написаны вообще не на C++, а на любом другом компилируемом языке. Главное, что бы соглашения о вызовах были указаны верные

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В C++ все хорошо с обратной совместимостью как между стандартами языка, так и с совместимостью с С. (Все плохо с совместимостью компиляторов, и stl разных поставщиков между собой.)

C++ библиотеки, как правило, бывают либо open-sources (и поставляются в исходниках), либо коммерческие (с закрытыми исходниками), поставляемые в виде .lib/.dll/.so.

Для open-sources обозначение версии языка - суть обозначение минимальной версии с помощью которой ее можно собрать. Т.е. если библиотеку нужно использовать в проекте, то просто собираете библиотеку и свой код одним компилятором (с одними и теми же настройками). Пример таких библиотек: boost.org

Коммерческие библиотеки, бывают двух видов: С-библиотеки, либо C++ библиотеки.
С-библиотеки хороши тем, что в отличии от C++, для них был принят стандартный ABI (application binary interface), и все его придерживаются. т.е. независимо от версии компилятора, скорее всего, вы сможете подключить библиотеку к своему проекту.
Причем не только к проекту на любом C++, но и к проекту на pascal или fortran.
Пример такой библиотеки: MKL.

С++-библиотеки позволяют предоставить более удобный интерфейс, но заставляют поставщика  привязываться к конкретным компиляторам (под windows). Часто, поставщик предоставляет бинарные файлы для нескольких популярных компиляторов, или может прислать отдельно бинарный файл для "вашего любимого" компилятора за отдельные деньги.

Под linux, в отличии от windows, С++ABI принят если не де-юре, то де-факто. Но разные версий stl и самих линуксов, сводят это преимуществено на нет.

Comment: "В C++ все хорошо … с совместимостью с С". К сожалению, изменения в стандарте С 2011г делает его не совместимым с С++ 2011. А с предыдущими версиям совместимость полная

Comment: @ГерманБорисов не совместим в каком смысле? Нельзя скомпилировать одним компилятором эти 2 разных версии? Или даже скомпилированные библиотеки нельзя использовать в более современном проекте?

Comment: @user347794, нельзя скомпилировать одним компилятором. Программа, написанная на всех стандартных диалектах С до 99 включительно была, в том числе, и корректной программой на С++. Но в С11 и С++11 было независимо введено ключевое слово auto с несколько разным смыслом. Уже скомпилированные библиотеки на C можно использовать независимо от версии компилятора (благодаря стандартизированному ABI)